# How do I make my Codename One sidemenu show in all forms?

Tags: codenameone

I have made my sidemenu global, but when I move to my second form, the hamburger Icon is not there and the sidemenu does not come out when I come to the side in the simulator. How do I make my sidemenu show throughout all forms in my app? If I have named the sidemenu in my first screen, do I have to use code to set the menu back up in the second form?

Comment: How did you make the sidemenu global? Notice that global toolbar doesn't make the sidemenu global. You have to actually add the side menu commands to every `Form` you create.

Comment: Thanks, Shai. I understand. I made the toolbar global. I will add my sidemenu code to my other forms. As a thought, it seems by my research into Codename One that using a train station form to move around my app is frowned upon, so I am trying to come up with a way for the sidemenu to serve as a hidden train station. The easiest way would be by having the Toolbar tb variable global, so it could be called from any form.

Comment: As another thought, do you see any inherent danger in creating a baseSideMenu class and then  creating and populating the side menu on the form that way?

Comment: You can't reuse the `Toolbar` since it's a `Component` and a `Component` may only have one parent. A typical approach is to create a base form and derive all our forms from it. Then the menu is constructed for all the forms in the same way.

Comment: Thanks. I will work on the base form approach.